# Word Document Paragraph break

Tags: c#, ms-word, document, paragraph

I was wondering if somebody found a way to add a pagebreak in front of a paragraph in case the paragraph would be split on 2 pages. Because I don't want this, I want all paragraphs I create to not be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the `Paragraph.KeepTogether` property. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.keeptogether.aspx), it keeps all lines of a paragraph on the same page.